# How to use Postman Soap request in PowerBi

Tags: soap, powerbi

I have a **SOAP request** which works fine(get a response from the server) in Postman application. Now I need to get data using PowerBI Application.

Is there any way to use Postman SOAP(which contain XML body, authentication, header ) request in PowerBI Application.

Answer (score 0):

Select get data and type web. Click on the Web and select advanced. Now you can fill in your postman SOAP data.
[image]